# How to keep the white space from a TEXT field when fetching

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL table, I have a `TEXT` field who contains Markdown text.

**Example:**

```
# Hello world

This is my __note__
```

However, when I'm fetching the data with PHP from the DB, it removes the white space.

**Example:**

```
# Hello world This is my __note__
```

**Question:**

What should I do to fetch my text exactly how it is in the DB?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The text is fetched exactly how it is in the DB. either it isn't in the DB the way you think, or you lose the whitespace after that.

Comment: Add the code you use to fetch and display the data to the question and someone might actually be able to help you.

Comment: How do you know the whitespace is removed while fetching and not while writing to output?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - How I fetch the text: `$row = $noteStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. In DB, the text looks like in the first example, but when I use the `die` function or `echo` to see how it looks in the browser, the second example occurs. Seems like `nl2br()` function is helping me to keep the white space.

Comment: Browsers reduce all consecutive whitespaces to a single blank when displaying HTML. nl2br() is one way of adding HTML line breaks, however what you need depends on how you want to display it. the database part is not your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display it on an HTML interpreting Web Browser, there are 2 ways to display as stored as in DB.

**1. Use <pre> tag**:
It is a tag that keeps pre-formation intact to display on a web browser. Enclose the content that has new line character in it.

**Example**:

```
<pre>
Hello world
This is my __note__
</pre>
```

**2. Use programming language provided function**:
PHP supports a function called ***`nl2br`*** that converts new line to HTML specific line break that is understandable by HTML interpreting Web Browsers.

**Example**:

```
$text_from_db_with_CRLF = '# Hello world\nThis is my __note__'  
echo nl2br( $text_from_db_with_CRLF );
```

**Documentation**:

- [`string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

  - Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you are print/echo it in browser, browser strip the extra spaces. Use strlen() in php to measure the string length or check it from cmd.